# WSO2 API Manager(2.1.0) - Provided Service Provider name is invalid

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using wso2am-2.1.0 and when I try to change the outbound configuration of a service provider I get the following error.

[image]

How can this be troubleshot?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What property are you going to change?

Comment: The authentication type from basic to adfs

Comment: Are you getting this for any SP?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this when I try to change other SPs as well.